# ILDASM получить IL код определенного куска кода

Tags: .net

Задача такова, есть С# код, нужно получить его IL код. Для этого я так понял используют дисасемблер ildasm.exe. Честно говоря не выходит\не понимаю как составить команду чтобы передать некоторый файл содержащий С# код и на выходе получить файл c IL кодом.

```
ildasm MyFile.exe /output:MyFile.il
```

Первый параметр передаем путь к exe-нику, второй параметр /output: передаем путь к директории создания MyFile.il. У меня не выходит передать целый путь к директории в обо параметра, или я чет не так понял. Кроме того, смотрю примеры использований, нельзя никак передать .cs файл с кодом, а не .exe.

Comment: Вы должны скомпилировать ваш C#-код, и скормить результат утилите `ildasm`. Утилита `ildasm` не скомпилирует для вас C# в exe/dll.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Сначала я так понял я превращаю свой код в .dll, и кидаю его на вход илдасму. Попробую

Comment: Именно так! Создать можно по идее и через CodeDOM, но можно запустить и стоковый компилятор.